# jenkins - How to create add button with drop down options

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I try to create new build step plugin.
In the GUI ( jelly ) I want to create the"Add" button with drop down list. Like we have in parameter job that we have a option to add diff parameter types ( String, choose, ...)

Can you please advise how to do it in jelly and what I need implement in java code?

Where I can find documentation for it?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this github repo](https://github.com/jayaprakashr/jenkins_corestack_plugin) which is a basic Jenkins plugins to connect Corestack orchestrator. Don't care about the application, but you can refer the implementation part on how to add a build/post build step in config.jelly and its corresponding java side implementation in CorestackNotifier.java soure code.

Comment: I will try to explain in more details what I need. My plugin can run "Type 1", "Type 2" and "Type 3" of different commands. So I search the way how I can create in my plugin the "Add" button that when you press on it you will get drop down with this 3 types.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from google groups.

You can find how to do it in the below post [1](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/introducing-variability-jenkins-plugins)